# How can I kill-ring-save one region's buffer with ediff?

Tags: emacs, emacs-ediff

I am doing an ediff in emacs and I want to copy the region in one of the buffers in order to paste it into a third buffer.  Obviously I can do this manually, but I'd like to be able to do it with a few keystrokes similar to how `a` and `b` can be used to replace one buffer's version with the other.

Is there a way to do this already?

If not, how should I go about implementing it?  I haven't done a lot of emacs programming before.

Answer (score 0):

Find `ediff-util.el` (it may be `ediff-util.el.gz` on your system). Read the function `ediff-copy-diff`. You want to mimic this behavior. Then you can add your new function to the ediff-mode keymap like this  `(define-key ediff-mode-map "a" 'ediff-copy-A-to-C)`.

Your function should probably be marked `(interactive)` and ask for a buffer name. See [Emacs interactive codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html) for details.